# Making Espresso wait for network calls, database work and other asynchronous tasks

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2, android-espresso

I have an application that uses UseCases to access a Repository. The UseCases subscribe on a thread pool, the repository makes network requests using OkHttp's thread pool and the repository also writes to a database that uses the Schedulers.io() thread pool.

For certain versions of Android I am having difficulties running UI tests using Espresso because my Idling Resources seem to go idle before all of the network requests / database writes are finished.

AFAIK, my setup uses three distinct thread pools. My thought was that if, in my UI test, I create an Idling Resource that watches each thread pool, then when I make a call to my Repository via my UseCase, Espresso will wait until all of the thread pools are idle before it advances my test code.

Here's an example of my test code:

```
    val wrapped: IdlingResourceScheduler = Rx2Idler.wrap(application.component.providesIoScheduler(), "IO Scheduler")
    val otherWrapped: IdlingResourceScheduler = Rx2Idler.wrap(application.component.providesJobScheduler(), "J O B")
    val resource = arrayOf<IdlingResource>(okHttpIdlingResource, wrapped, otherWrapped)
    idlingRegistry.goIdle(*resource) {
        onView(withId(R.id.toolbar_main))
                .check(matches(isDisplayed()))
    }
```

What I think I'm doing in the above code is registering an idling resource for my database thread pool, my OkHttp thread pool and my UseCase thread pool. So my thought was that at least one of those thread pools would always be 'active' when a call is made to my Repository and once the Repository has returned its value, all of the thread pools would be idle and Espresso would know that it is ok to advance the test. Like I said above, that seems to be true for devices running Marshmallow (and maybe even higher versions) but does not work for devices on Pie.

Here is a simplified example of my UseCase:

```
repository
    .authenticate(params.username, params.password)
    .subscribeOn(My Use Case Thread Pool)
    .observeOn(Main Thread)
```

Here is a simplified example of the auth method in my Repository class:

```
Single.zip(networkLayer.authenticate(username, password), 
    userDao.getUserInfo(), 
    BiFunction { t1, t2 -> Result(t1,t2) }
    .flatMap {
         Single.just(deleteAllDataFromDatabase())
             .flatMap {
                 networkLayer.getRestOfData()
             }
    }
```

What I really can't understand is why the test runs on some versions but not others. I also can't understand why, if I watch all of the thread pools for idleness, how can Espresso advance the test? Won't at least one of my thread pools be doing something (either fetching from the network, writing to the database, or doing something in the Use Case? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You need to move all the async logic in the same thread. You can do that using this testing rule for RxJava/RxAndroid

```
class ImmediateSchedulersRule : TestRule {
    override fun apply(base: Statement, description: Description): Statement {
        return object : Statement() {
            @Throws(Throwable::class)
            override fun evaluate() {
                RxJavaPlugins.setIoSchedulerHandler { Schedulers.trampoline() }
                RxJavaPlugins.setComputationSchedulerHandler { Schedulers.trampoline() }
                RxJavaPlugins.setNewThreadSchedulerHandler { Schedulers.trampoline() }
                RxAndroidPlugins.setInitMainThreadSchedulerHandler { Schedulers.trampoline() }
                try {
                    base.evaluate()
                } finally {
                    RxJavaPlugins.reset()
                    RxAndroidPlugins.reset()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And add this rule to your testing classes:

```
@get:Rule
var immediateRule = ImmediateSchedulersRule()
```

---

By the way, if you can refactor your use case, a better solution could be to pass a `Scheduler` object to each of your use cases.

Something like that:

Have the schedulers in its own file and create a default one:

```
interface AppScheduler {
    fun io(): Scheduler
    fun computation(): Scheduler
    fun main(): Scheduler
}

class DefaultAppScheduler : AppScheduler {
    override fun io() = Schedulers.io()
    override fun computation() = Schedulers.computation()
    override fun main() = AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()
}
```

Your use case has the AppScheduler injected (or passed manually if you are not using Dagger or similar), and in normal application you will pass the `DefaultAppScheduler` implementation.

```
class TestUseCase @Inject constructor(
    private val scheduler: AppScheduler,
    private val yourRepository: YourRepository
) : BaseUseCase<Unit, List<Object>>() {

    //I have omitted some details here but you can get the point
    fun createObservable(params: Unit): Flowable<List<Object>> {
        return yourRepository.loadDataList()
            .subscribeOn(scheduler.io())
    } 
}
```

Then in your test code you will create a new `AppScheduler` implementation just for testing using the `trampoline` one:

```
class TestAppScheduler : AppScheduler {
    override fun io() = Schedulers.trampoline()
    override fun computation() = Schedulers.trampoline()
    override fun main() = Schedulers.trampoline()
}
```

In this way your test will wait before proceeding.

Comment: This solution worries me because I'm no longer testing the actual implementation of the app, right? The real app runs using multiple thread pools and the test version essentially all runs on one thread. Can I still be confident that the tests verify the real behavior of the app then?

Comment: You dont need to test the threading model. You want to test that your app behaves like expected from the logic you wrote, so yes. If the test passes you will be confident that your logic is ok (independently of the thread where it will be executed)

Comment: I understand that I'm not testing the threading model and that RxJava abstracts the thread management away, but since my test is running against a mock server, my thought was that I want a real implementation of everything to be exercised in the test. However, it does make sense that, if RxJava is capable of working with multiple thread pools, then running a test with one background thread should work and swapping in multiple thread pools in the real implementation works as well. But it still seems if I want to do a true e2e test that this solution isn't really performing a full system test.

Comment: You said your test are running against a mocked server. This is the first thing should help you understand that you want to remove the "external factor", otherwise you could do tests with you real endpoint. Testing is mostly performed in the way I told you, can find plenty of articles online about the same problem and all with similar solutions. A real end-to-end test is something really difficult to mantain and usually what you do is: I have A <-> B <-> C as Use Case of clean architecture. If I have test between A <-> B and B <-> C I'm pretty sure logic is still valid between A - C

Comment: Without the need to create specific tests between A <-> C flow